# Prevent third party plugin's admin page access based on user type

Tags: plugin-development, wp-admin, user-roles

Am using a third party plugin(eg. ABC Plugin). And their code doesn't have any hooks or filters. And they don't provide customization based on our requirements.

So if I modify the plugin code, I would have to duplicate the changes each time when an update is available for that plugin.

Hence I decided to create a plugin, that will work along with the other plugin, and make the necessary modifications.

Right now, I want to limit the access to a specific url of the plugin page (in admin panel), only to a specific user type.
And the url is like `https://mywebsite.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=abcplugin&route_name=customers__index`

Am thinking to use the `admin_init` hook to check whether the current requested url is the above, by simply doing `if( $_GET['page']=='abcplugin') && $_GET['route_name']=='customers__index')`

But am not sure how to show the `You do not have permission to access this page` error message. Any inputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's done with `wp_die()`.

Something along these lines:

`if ( $no_user_access ) {
    wp_die( 'You do not have permission to access this page' );
}`

See: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_die/

Comment: Thank you. That helped.